# jQuery Accordion drop down not working

Tags: jquery

Repost of old question with cleaner code:

Trying the make [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rexonms/Bchjk/3/) accordion work. But the conditional statement is not working. The li > li suppose to show up when a user hover overs li.

Thanks in advance

http://jsfiddle.net/rexonms/Bchjk/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Sidebar Accordion Nav
    $("#linkListSub3 li li").hide();

    $("#linkListSub3 li").hover(function() {

         if( $("li",this ).is(":hidden") ) {
              alert("What what");

        $("#linkListSub3 li li").next().slideUp();
        $(this).next().slideDown();
    }
        return false;
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Bchjk/8/

changed

```
 if( $(this > li).is(":hidden") ) {
```

to

```
 if( $("li",this ).is(":hidden") ) {
```

You cannot just concatenate a DOM element and a string...

Comment: super duper thanks a lot now for taking care of the logic. I made few other changes with in conditional statement and now it work.